# openSuse 11.3 usb mouse & usb keyboard problems

Tags: opensuse

I've just installed openSuse 11.3 and when I plug-in my usb mouse or usb keyboard seem nothing happens. 
What is the problem is there any quick issues/solutions on it? The reason I'm not familiar to openSuse.

Sultan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=638200
this bug is fixed by kernel rpm 2.6.34.7
although the changelog in the rpm does not reference bnc#638200.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem since a few days. The first keystrokes are not recognized. Unfortunately the workaround posted here does not work for me, AutoAddDevices = off on a notebook is not a solution.

There is a solution posted at the OpenSUSE forums:
http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-help-here/hardware/445907-keyboard-mouse-freezes-11.html

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue.  I found a [bug report](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=585617) for it.
Booting to runlevel 3 and adding the following to the ServerFlags section of /etc/X11/xorg.conf:

option  "AutoAddDevices" "off"

seems to fix the mouse and keyboard issue (on my laptop), but nothing else seems to work properly.

I am going back to 11.2 for the time being.

---

Run Xorg -configure to create an xorg.conf.new file in your home directory.  You can then copy that to /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Then add the following:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
    option  "AutoAddDevices"  "off"
EndSection
```

Comment: I'm confused a bit because there is no xorg.conf at /etc/X11/ instead of it I see xorg.conf.d directory but nothing like ServerFlags section.

Comment: Just an update.  I wiped my /root partition and did a fresh install of 11.3 and everything is working fine.